# how to specify 2 file name conditions in shell "find" cmd?

Tags: linux, bash

I need to search for all files - in cur dir and all subdirs with a name ending by ~, or a name that start and end by #, delete all files found.
this not working, it does not display found files

```
find -type f  -name "~" or "#*#"  ls -a -delete
```

and this is not working with piping:

```
find -type f  -name "~" or "#*#" | ls -a | -delete
```

how to specify both conditions?

EDIT: The command line will find files matching the condition, print and then delete them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-o` (=or; the implicit default is `-a` = and) to combine operators and `\(`/`\)` to specify operator precedence:

```
find -type f \( -name "~" -o -name "#*#" \) -delete
```

You can combine multiple actions, e.g. outputting and deleting at the same time by simply providing all required actions:

```
find -type f \( -name "~" -o -name "#*#" \) -print -delete
```

Comment: @knitls thx u , and also how to display files before deleting? i m not sure piping works..

Comment: @ERJAN simplest is to run the command twice: once without `-delete` (printing is the default action) and once with `-delete`

Comment: hmm but i need to make it one liner. for some reason "find -type f \( -name "~" -o -name "#*#" \) | ls | -delete" is not working

Comment: find . -type f -regex '.*~$' -or -regex '.*#$'

Comment: @c4f4t0r thx , regex is not that crucial how do i show all those files that match condition??

Comment: @ERJAN this work for me find . \( -regex '.*~$' -or -regex '.*#$' \) -exec rm -v {} \;

Comment: @c4f4t0r thx ,and how to display them all? using ls is not working for me

Comment: Just `-print -delete`.... Doing `ls | something` will be passing the output of `ls` to that `something`, that is what pipe `|` does.

Comment: @KamilCuk my line "find . -type f -regex '.*~$' -or -regex '*.*#$' -print -delete
" is not showing and deleting everything

Comment: alright this one works ! thx everyone, find -type f \( -name "*~" -o -name "#*#" \) -print  -delete

Answer (score 1):

An other option would be to simply filter the results with grep

```
find -type f | grep -E '(~|#*#)' | xargs rm
```

That would also allow to build additional steps (like displaying the files) into it